# Troubles with generics

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, hashmap, hashtable

I wanted to create a list of lists. (Structure like that `List<Node<>>`.) (Nodes are connected so that every address is stored in memory until the next. List is ArrayList.) I want to code a hash table, but I am stuck in creating the data structure.

```
public class RazpršenaTabela<E extends Oseba> extends AbsTab<E> {


List<Node<>> ort=new ArrayList<Node<>>();
```

I have got an error:
illegal start of type

### illegal start of type

(Alt-Enter shows hints)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign what type of node are you using, assuming it'll be a string node you'll have something like:

```
List<Node<String>> ort=new ArrayList<Node<String>>();
```

Comment: yeah just do `for(Node<String> node : ort)`...If you want something generic use Object instead of string

Comment: in other tables (one linked table) i have got iterator like this:

Comment: i cannt past there .(

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kNNz3hLk and then i must make for this but i dont know how with two parameters ..